# Replacing a line with / linux

Tags: linux, shell

My file content is like the below in Linux box,

```
"Value=/test/home/file/plugin.log"/>
```

I am trying below command to replace the line but its not working,

```
#!/bin/bash
PS='/test/home/file/plugin.log'
PT='/test/home/control/file/plugin.log'

sed -e "s@/${PS}@/${PT}@" filename > "filename_new"
```

Can you pls enlighten me where I am doing wrong.

Thanks,
Kumar

Answer (score 0):

You have extra `/` after regex delimiter. Use:

```
sed "s@$PS@$PT@" filename > "filename_new"
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.